# What path is needed to run homebrew cask installed apps from the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, homebrew, path

I installed Thunderbird using homebrew cask. I am using Intel Processor.

```
/Applications/Thunderbird.app/Contents/MacOS/thunderbird -whatever
```

How can I use the command line options of thunderbird on macOS so I don’t have to pass the full path /Applications each time I want to start the app?

Comment: Are you looking for how to do something like this? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1304471 or https://support.mozilla.org/sv/questions/1243720

Comment: @bmike No I have installed using homebrew cask, I don't thing the link is relevant

Comment: @Porcupine Homebrew Cask installs the same way a regular install would work. You should follow the same debugging steps as if you hadn't used Homebrew Cask.

Comment: @Ezekiel Thanks! Yes I could access the binary using the full path /Applications/Thunderbird.app/Contents/MacOS/thunderbird. May I ask you if its possible to add this in a PATH variable of all binaries, so that I don't have to type the entire path? I am referring to PATH variable in Linux, I hope something like that is there in MacOS?

Comment: @Porcupine Setting PATH basically works the same on Linux and macOS.

Comment: @nohillside Yes I understand but Linux puts all binary in a separate `bin` folder, which contains only binary. But Application folder in MacOS clearly contains a lot of other stuff apart from binary file. I have several applications imnstalled in Applications folder using Homebrew Cask and each have a different folder structure to the location of the binary. Is there a way where all binaries can be symlinked to a single location, so that one path can be added in in PATH variable to cover all binaries?

Comment: You can either manually symlink them all into one location and add that one to PATH, or add all locations to PATH individually, or work with shell aliases; there are probably even more ways. Pick the one which suits you best, it seems as if you know the steps already.

Comment: Having said that: The binaries in `/Applications` are always in `/Applications/NAME.APP/Contents/MacOS`, the other directories within .APP are just part of the installation.

Comment: @nohillside I have been using Linux for years and I understand the concepts. Got into MacOs last week and I am dealing with its peculiarities! Thats unfortunate if one needs to update the path varibale manually after installing each app!

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60582273/7445342

Comment: @SiGe Unfortunately with your method I can't pass command line arguments

Comment: @Porcupine Look at the open man page --args is the parameter you need